# What Web Server Was Used Before Apache

Tags: web-server, web

What did the majority of websites use as web server, before Apache in 1995?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apache About page describes it all: http://httpd.apache.org/ABOUT_APACHE.html

There was a product called "NCSA httpd" which was in general use before Apache came about. It didn't take long for Apache to pass httpd up as the #1 deployed web-server. The curve can be found in the NetCraft web-surveys ([link](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2011/01/12/january-2011-web-server-survey-4.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Well, apache was [a patchy webserver](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_company_name_etymologies) - a set of patches to the NCSA httpd webserver.  The [NCSA webserver wikipedia page](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/NCSA_HTTPd) says that NCSA httpd ran 95% of websites when apache took over, so I would say NCSA httpd is your answer.

Interestingly, [this post](http://dan.hersam.com/2004/07/29/a-patchy-web-server/) indicates that the Apache foundation now advances a completely different derivation for the name.